# "Néron-Ogg-Shafarevich criterion" in positive characteristic

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

The Néron-Ogg-Shafarevich theorem usually seems to be cited to say that an abelian variety over a finite extension $K/{Q}_p$ has good reduction at $\ell \neq p$ if and only if the associated $\ell$-adic Galois representation (Tate module) is unramified, as seen in Serre-Tate. I am aware that these conditions can be slightly generalized (cf. the Néron models book). I also know that you get the analogous result at $\ell = p$ if you replace "unramified" by "crystalline," but that this was proven much more recently.

However, from skimming the proofs of these various results, I don't immediately see where the fact that $K$ is characteristic zero is used. For instance, Serre-Tate doesn't seem to say anything about the characteristic of $K$. Nevertheless, I haven't yet seen this theorem applied when $K$ has positive characteristic, and some of the results (e.g. the Coleman-Iovita paper where it is shown if the p-adic Tate module is crystalline, then the abelian variety has good reduction) do assume that $K$ is characteristic zero (and perfect residue field, but I am less concerned about this).

I guess I have a couple of related questions:

- Does the Néron-Ogg-Shafarevich theorem for abelian varieties hold when $K$ has positive characteristic? If so, could you link to a paper where it is applied in this fashion?
- Can you get similar results "at $p$" when char$(K) = p > 0$?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is true in the function field setting.  This will follow
from the Neron models argument in Serre--Tate.

Note that "crystalline" only makes sense in the mixed char. setting.
If you work directly with $p$-divisible groups (i.e. talk about the
$p$-divisible group extending over the ring of integers) then the
result should be true in the char. $p$ setting.  My feeling is that
this kind of thing would be proved in the part of SGA7 dealing with
Neron models.  (E.g. an extension of the Neron mapping to $p$-divisible
groups is proved in there somewhere, although I forget the precise 
statement or hypotheses.)  I'm always made a bit nervous about non-perfect
residue fields too, so let me not commit to anything on that point, since
I'm just writing off the top of my head.